# How to make border radius for first letter in <span> and align it

Tags: position, alignment, padding, css

I have 3 inline blocks with "lorem ipsum" text.
They have header and content.
First letter in the header, using `::first-letter`, have different color-background and border radius.
But I can't align all first letters correctly, so I make "personal" `padding` rule for each of them, like this one:

```
.info.red .first::first-letter {
    background-color: #f17c72;
    padding: 0 18px 0 18px;

} 

.info.gray .first::first-letter {
    background-color: #aaaeb8;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;

} 

.info.blue .first::first-letter {
    background-color: #33516b;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

Can I set position for first letter of span more easily ?
And second question is about how to make text in  to be near first letter with same side margin (See picture in the bottom of the demo) ?
Demo with both questions on **[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YLrLvsQTYsT7VwjX3awW?p=preview)**

Comment: You can try floating the first-letter to the left and play with margin to align it, check this http://plnkr.co/edit/mvBTAlWWmjJkKVsJ1P99?p=preview . Try expanding the window large enough to see it aligned correctly, of course when the window's width is small, the text will be wrapped and does not look good.

Comment: @KingKing, that's awesome, thanks a lot !  
Can you advice something about my border-radius question ?

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand your border-radius problem.

Comment: @KingKing sorry, it's seems everything is okay now. sorry for disturbing

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display block the first letter, so each one is a different size because each letter is a different size.  Unfortunately your only option would be to wrap each letter in a span which you can display:block and give a set width/height to

Comment: I just can't get how do achieve this in other way.
Can you show me a demo of other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Here, worked a little on your code and it seem to work just fine, every first letter will have the same width if you put them in float left and the text of the first line will come floating on the left of the letter. No need for custom padding for each of them.

```
    .info .first::first-letter {
        border-radius: 100%;
        font-size: 50px;
        color: #f4f2f0;
        float: left;
        margin: -10px 5px 0 0;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        text-align: center;
    }


    .info span {
        font-weight: bold;
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }

    .info.red .first::first-letter {
        background-color: #f17c72;

    } 

    .info.gray .first::first-letter {
        background-color: #aaaeb8;

    } 

    .info.blue .first::first-letter {
        background-color: #33516b;
    }
```